# Show previous nonblank/non-zero value from rows

Tags: powerbi

I am working in PowerBI, and I would like to ask you for help with following issue:

I have weekly data and I want to show data from previous week/row is separate column.
I was able to do that, but I have problem with blank/zero values.

Instead of zero I would like to use previous non-zero/non-blank value - so, the goal is to have columns: value and highlighted column (see below).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2wY3.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: You need it using DAX? or transformation layer?

Comment: Thank you for reply, It should be with using of DAX.

Comment: Can you please shown your current code?

Comment: I just used just this
column = LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[Value], 'Table'[Index],'Table'[Index]-1)

which returns previous row value,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this below code for Measure-

```
column_new = 

var curr_row_index = min('Table'[Index])

var max_index_before = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Table'[Index]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(Table),
        'Table'[Index] < curr_row_index
            && 'Table'[Value] > 0
    )

)

return 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Table'[Value]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(Table),
        'Table'[Index] = max_index_before 
    )

)
```

update:

```
column_new_ = 

var curr_row_index = min('Table'[Index])
var curr_row_value = min('Table'[Value])

var max_index_before = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Table'[Index]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(Table),
        'Table'[Index] < curr_row_index
            && 'Table'[Value] > 0
    )

)

var last_non_zero_value =  
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Table'[Value]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(Table),
        'Table'[Index] = max_index_before 
    )

)

return if(
    ISBLANK(last_non_zero_value), BLANK(),
    if(
        curr_row_value >= last_non_zero_value, 
        curr_row_value - last_non_zero_value, 
        curr_row_value
    )
)
```

Comment: I have tried it and as a measure it shows required data, thank you very much for that.

I just wonder if there is a possibility to include this in condition.

IF value>=previous non zero value THEN value - previous non zero value, ELSE value)

Comment: Should be possible. I will try.

Comment: Nice to hear that. You can also put an upvote to the answer :)